# Errors uploading more than one file in laravel 5

Tags: php, jquery, laravel

I am building a form that allows users upload more than one file provided they click on the 'Add more files' link. When I upload more than one file, for example, 2 files, I see the 2 files in the folder I store files but in database table, its only the first of the 2 files that is saved on the table. And it is saved twice. For instance, if I upload 3 files, the first of the 3 files is saved 3 times on the table but the 3 individual files I can see in the folder. Whats the problem here?

My view:

```
<label class="control-label mb-10" for="exampleInputuname_1">Uploads</label>
<input type="file" class="form-control" id="exampleInputuname_1"
                                       name="file[]" required>
<a class="add_more" href="">Add More Files</a>
```

JQuery

```
 $( function() {
            $('.add_more').click(function(e){
                e.preventDefault();
                $(this).before("<input name='file[]' type='file' class='form-control'/>");
            });
 });
```

My controller

```
foreach ($files as $file) {

                            $file_extension = $file->getClientOriginalExtension();
                            $new_name = base64_encode(date('Y-m-d H:i:s') . $file->getClientOriginalName()) . '.' . $file_extension;
                            $destinationPath = 'uploads/files';
                            $file->move($destinationPath, $new_name);
                            $filename = $destinationPath . '/' . $new_name;
                            $i++;
                            $uri = Utilities::generateFileRef($i);

                            File::create([
                                'uri' => $uri,
                                'user_id' => $user_id,
                                'title' => $request->folder_name,
                                'document' => $filename,
                                'folder_id' => $folder_id
                            ]);

                        }
```

Comment: Set `<input type="file" class="form-control" id="exampleInputuname_1"
                                       name="file[]" required>` to `<input type="file[]" class="form-control" id="exampleInputuname_1"
                                       name="file[]" required>`

Comment: What is this? Did you read what you wrote????????

Comment: Have you tried? In form you have field for one file. How ever if form is extended with more fields you are instantiating array i.e. `file != file[]`.

Comment: Why make life hard? Just add `multiple` to the `<input>` tag